# Finding optimal threshold using small world network metrics to binarize 2 groups for comparison

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

I have two groups *(GROUP1 and GROUP2)* of undirected weighted graphs - one having properties more similar to small world network and other relatively random. These are represented as adjacency matrices with 32 nodes and weights 0 to 1 representing connectivity strength among nodes.

I am taking help of **small world network** metrics to find threshold (ranging between 0.01 to 0.9) for both the graphs. This threshold will be used to drop weak connections in both groups and convert adjacency matrices to binarized matrices (with value 1 or 0 only). Currently the **algorithm** I am using is:

1. Initializing variable *thresholds* = 0.1 to 0.9 with step size = 0.002
2. Initialize an empty list *ratios*
3. For each threshold in thresholds:

   3.1 Calculate binary matrices for *GROUP1* and *GROUP2* using the current threshold (matrix > threshold).

   3.2 Take average of all connected components in  a graph and find small world network metrics - shortest average path length (Lw) and clustering coefficient (CC): We get **Lw_1, CC_1 for *GROUP1* and Lw_2 and CC_2 for *GROUP2*.**

   where, **Lw** = the average minimum number of edges that must be traversed to go from one node to another node in the network and **CC** = measures the degree to which its neighbors are themselves connected.

- For **SWN** (small world network), CC is high and Lw is low.
- For **random network**, both CC and Lw is high.
- For a **disconnected** component, both Lw and CC is 0.

  3.3. Calculate *swi_ratio* using the formula = (Cw_1/Lw_1)/(Cw_2/Lw_2) that is *small world index of GROUP1/ small world index of GROUP2* if any graph is not connected else swi_ratio = 0

  3.4 Append swi_ratio to ratios list

4.Determine the optimal threshold which will be the maximum absolute value in ratios list

**Questions:**

1. Is taking ratio of GROUP1/GROUP2 metrics the correct approach ? I have taken it as such to preserve small world network as Most of the network in real world follows small world network. The GROUP1 has relative random network and GROUP2 has small world network.
2. Even if the graph is disconnected, I am finding the connected components and returning Lw and CC of each connected components (may range from 1 to all 32) and averaging it. I did this because just passing the graph was giving very low threshold as optimal one and not giving me desired results. Was this modification okay?
3. Also, making swi_ratio = 0 correct ? if any graph is not connected because at high thresholds, connected components are 32 and Lw and CC both are 0 which will return division by 0 error.